# Share button in ActionBar icon not default. How to change it?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, icons

I added share button to my ActionBar, but icon of that button seems not ok.

Default button looks like that:
https://monosnap.com/image/yiBpHo6XcMWKmXD1zwcy2w2gRkFBPN.png

But in my case it looks just like "SHARE" textin actionBar:
https://monosnap.com/image/d8cXbr5XIFtwItoaXAKkTjVBPr5eEa.png

How to change it to default?

Here is my menu xml file for activity:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.app.SomeActivity" >
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass= "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this

> android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"

Comment: Thanks alot! My problem is I dont know what adress have that icon. 
It works.

Comment: @udenfox you can find it in your
\sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res

Comment: I use Android Studio 1.2.2, working a project with APIs min=19,max=22 and I needed to do `android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha` to show up the default icon. Thank you and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
   android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: why ic_launcher icon?

Comment: use Your Image Icon In The Place Of ic_launcher icon

Comment: For this to be a useful answer, you need to explain what you've changed and how it answers the question, not just paste code and hope they get it.

Comment: I understand the code and I know how to change icon to my own. But I need to use default icon which in SDK. Kristijan Drača getted me what I need.